# Number of WAL files over the limit: StdOut Line Count

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I have the postgresql server in which i have configured the ma_wal_segments=1gb in the postgresql.conf. But i am always getting the alert "number of WAL files over the limit: StdOut Line Count". How to overcome this problem.

i have set the max_wal_segments=2GB or 1.6GB but same error"number of WAL files over the limit: StdOut Line Count" getting

edited postgresql.conf 
max_wal_segments=2GB

I don't wal "number of WAL files over the limit: StdOut Line Count" this alert.

Comment: Do you mean `max_wal_size`? There is no option `max_wal_segments`. Also: how is that number "calculated" and where does the error come from (it's not a Postgres error message)

Comment: yes max_wal_size....I have configured the scenario in Zabbix ticketing the tool. i am getting alert on the tool.

Comment: What version of postgres?  Are you archiving WAL files or using replication?

Comment: Version 10 and using archiving WAL files.